# Is there a tool to generate javadoc that automatically generates @see references to called methods?

Tags: javadoc

I know how to generate simple javadoc for a method, but I thought it would be very useful to automatically include links to the methods that my method calls.  Is there any tool that will scan the method code and automatically place @see references to called methods for me in the javadoc?  A quick example:

If I have a method A that calls B, C, and D, it would be great to append javadoc to A's javadoc that indicates that it calls B, C and D (along with @see links to those methods so you can read the javadoc for them).

What I'm really looking for is a tool that will generate process flow documentation where all I do is document my code like I normally do, run this tool, and then I end up with documentation that will tell me what my method does, and all of the other methods that it calls (preferably in the order that the methods are called).

Surely such a tool exists (probably multiple ones of them), and I bet there are a lot of opinions on which one is the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "Doxygen".

You can get the relationship of functions even without @see tag.

Remember to edit the conf file, make sure you have turn on "function_call" switch.(Sorry I am not quite sure about the switch name)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such a tool exists. I hope it doesn't. The point of documentation is to make things clearer, and I think if an `@see` is added to each method call, you'd end up with a pile of spaghetti. (Delicious, but nothing you want to sort through.) You should rather restrict `@see`'s to relevant or related methods.

Of course you can add the code into the javadoc, and there *might* be a way to get the source code method calls to link to the Javadoc. Certainly you can jump to method declaration in Eclipse with the 'Open Declaration (F3)' option.

Comment: I am working in a task-based framework, where each task class is very small and calls a relatively small number of other tasks.  It would be very helpful in this case to know what tasks call what other tasks. In general, though, I agree with you.